# Increment a value at address of an arrray in NASM assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, nasm

In my `.bss` section I declare `array db 5, 4, 3, 2, 1`

I then have a pointer `ptr` defined as `%define ptr dword[ebp-8]`

I would like to inc and dec this pointer at will to move from one element in the array to another, and then I would like to have to ability to `inc` the value in the array that the pointer is pointing to, and have this ***be updated in the array!***

I move through the array with a loop in the form of:

```
mov ptr, array ; not in loop
mov ebx, ptr
mov al, [ebx]
inc ptr
```

How can I increment the value and then have it saved in the array instead of just some register as if I did `inc al` , can I do something like `inc [ptr]` (This doesnt work ofcourse). Is there a better way to approach this entirely?

Thanks

Edit:

I want my array to be something like `10, 8, 6, 5, 2` i.e increment each element by however many

Comment: Just keep your pointer in a register in the first place like a normal person (like EBX).  You can of course do `inc byte [ebx]`, or store the updated value of `al` using `mov`.

Comment: And BTW, yes you could do `inc ptr`, which looks funny because you included square brackets in the macro definition.

Comment: Also, if you want to double each element, you should load it, do `add al,al`, then store it.  Although IDK why you double the first 3, but add 3 to the `2`, and tack on an extra `1` making a 6-element array when there were originally 5.  You can't add new elements to static arrays, unless you already reserved space for them (like some `0` bytes after?)

Answer (score 2):

> In my `.bss` section I declare `array db 5, 4, 3, 2, 1`

This does not make sense.
*By default* `.bss` is defined as `nobits`, i. e. an *uninitialized* section (although a modern multi-user OS will initialize it with some values [usually zero] to prevent data leaks).
You probably meant to write `.data` section.
`nasm(1)` will issue an “ignored” warning about any `db` in a `nobits` section.

> I then have a pointer `ptr` defined as `%define ptr dword[ebp‑8]`
>
> I would like to inc and dec this pointer […]

No, you have a (case-sensitive) single-line macro `ptr`.
Any (following) occurrence of `ptr` will be expanded to `dword[ebp‑8]`.
Use `nasm ‑E source.asm` (preprocess only) to show this.

> […] then I would like to have to ability to `inc` the value in the array that the pointer is pointing to […]

Your `ptr` macro says it’s pointing to a `dword` – a 32‑bit quantity – but your `array` consists of `db` – data Byte, 8‑bit quantity – elements.
This doesn’t add up.

> I want my array to be something like `10, 8, 6, 5, 2` i.e increment each element by however many

Well, x + x = 2 × x, calculating the sum of a value plus the same value is the same as multiplying by two.
Any decent compiler will [optimize multiplying by a constant factor 2ⁿ as a `shl x, n`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift).
Unless you need certain flags (the resulting flags of `shl` and `add` marginally differ), you can do something like

```
    lea ebx, [array]            ; load address of start of `array`
    xor eax, eax                ; eax ≔ 0, index in array starting at 0
    mov ecx, 5                  ; number of elements
head_of_loop:
    shl byte [ebx + 1 * eax], 1 ; base address + size of element * index
    add eax, 1                  ; eax ≔ eax + 1
    loop head_of_loop           ; ecx ≔ ecx − 1
                                ; if ecx ≠ 0 then goto head_of_loop
```

The constant factor in `[ebx + 1 * eax]` can be `1`, `2`, `4` or `8`.
Note, the [`loop` instruction is utterly slow](/q/35742570/) and was used just for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: "In “long mode” it can be `8`, too."  Not true! These four scale factors are always available. They belong to the SIB encoding and have no relation with any mode of operation the CPU is in.

Comment: @SepRoland Duly noted. Thanks.